# MySQL reference outer table alias in subquery error

Tags: mysql

```
  select c.*
    from posts p
    join comments c on (p.id=c.post_id) 
        and c.status = 'A' 
        and c.id >= (select MIN(id) from (select id from comments where post_id=p.id order by id DESC LIMIT 7) as c2)
    where p.comments_count > 0 AND p.id IN (247,245,244,243,242,241)
```

In the above sql query I get this mysql error **Unknown column 'p.id' in 'where clause'** it seems like in the subquery p.id isn't able to get referenced. Is there anyway that I can get the posts table id referenced in this subquery?

Comment: Can you show the schema for your posts? Is it really `id` or `post_id`?

Comment: provide two tables columns.

Comment: Yep I want to find up to the 7th most recent comments id with the subquery so I can limit the number of comments per post, I can definitely add schema info if that doesn't make sense and I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to fetch latest 7 comments for each post. Could you try this? you can test here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a222e/3/0

**The First Attempt**

I tried below SQL.

```
SELECT *
FROM comments t1
WHERE post_id IN (247,254,244,243,242,241)
AND id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM comments
    WHERE t1.id = id
    LIMIT 7
);
```

But I got an error *"This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery"*

### Another Approach

So, I tried self join on comments to generate sequence number.

```
SELECT id
FROM (
    SELECT t1.id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM comments t1 INNER JOIN comments t2
      ON t1.post_id = t2.post_id
    WHERE t1.id <= t2.id
      AND t1.post_id IN (247,254,244,243,242,241)
      AND t2.post_id IN (247,254,244,243,242,241)
    GROUP BY t1.id
) x
WHERE cnt <= 7;
```

**inner sub-query** uses self join and produces `cnt` column which has sequential value for each comment id of post.

But preceding query only fetches `id` of comment

**Finally** to get all columns of comment table, following query should be executed.

```
SELECT *
FROM comments c INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id
    FROM (
        SELECT t1.id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM comments t1 INNER JOIN comments t2
          ON t1.post_id = t2.post_id
        WHERE t1.id <= t2.id
          AND t1.post_id IN (247,254,244,243,242,241)
          AND t2.post_id IN (247,254,244,243,242,241)
        GROUP BY t1.id
    ) x
    WHERE cnt <= 7
) t USING (id);
```

### Using User Variables

Actually you have another chance using MySQL `user variable`. I didn't mention this interesting MySQL feature because I was not sure I understood your question correctly.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT post_id, id,
        IF (@pid = post_id, @cnt := @cnt + 1, @cnt := 1) AS cnt,
        @pid := post_id
    FROM comments, (SELECT @pid := 0, @cnt := 0) tmp
    WHERE post_id IN (247,254,244,243,242,241)
    ORDER BY post_id, id DESC
) x
WHERE cnt <= 7;
```

Preceding SQL looks like simpler (means good performance) than older join version. but not tested on large data set.

Comment: Thanks InoS Heo this looks promising. I'll test it out further and report back. BTW I also got that error "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery" on one of my attempts where I didn't use MIN but instead just used IN with the main subquery part.

Comment: Works perfect for me thanks! I was tempted to move to PostgreSQL where this kind of thing seems a bit easier to accomplish but this is good enough for me for now with MySQL. Thanks!

Comment: @user3175934 My Pleasure. I have added another query. It might help you also.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access the outer query 1 level deep. So try doing you where filter on the middle query:

```
SELECT MIN(id)
FROM (
    SELECT id, post_id 
    FROM   comments 
    ORDER  BY id DESC 
    LIMIT  7
)
WHERE post_id = p.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however it doesn't seem to limit the comments to the specific post.

Comment: Also thanks for letting me know about the 1 level deep alias access.